# Como converter um caractere para seu hexadecimal correspondente na tabela ASCII em Ruby?

Tags: string, ruby, ascii

Estou utilizando Ruby e possuo a sequência de caracteres `"AwX"` em hexadecimal. Eu consigo escrever na tela usando o seguinte comando:

```
puts "\x41\x77\x58"
```

Porém eu quero fazer o inverso: eu tenho uma string `"AwX"`, mas quero recuperar os hexadecimais desses caracteres (seja como array de strings, string única ou outros formatos) e escrever o resultado na tela (com os caracteres sendo representados na notação hexadecimal, como sendo "0x41", "\x41" ou outros formatos). Como essa conversão dos caracteres pode ser realizada?

Tentei utilizar as funções `string.hex` e `string.to_i`:

```
puts "A".hex # esperava "x41", mas foi retornado 10
puts "A".to_i(base=16) # esperava "x41", mas foi retornado 10
puts "A".to_i.to_s(16) # esperava "x41", mas foi retornado 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [método `codepoints`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-codepoints), que retorna um array com os valores numéricos correspondentes aos caracteres da string, e em seguida basta convertê-los para o formato desejado:

```
puts "AwX".codepoints.map { |i| "0x" + i.to_s(16) }.join()

puts "AwX".codepoints.map { |i| format("\\x%X", i)}.join()
```

No primeiro caso usei o prefixo `0x` e `to_s` para converter para hexa, e no segundo, usei o prefixo `\x` e [`format`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Kernel.html#method-i-format) para imprimir o número em hexa (apenas para mostrar duas formas diferentes de fazer).

Em ambos os casos usei [`join`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-join) no final, para juntar tudo em uma única string. A saída é:

```
0x410x770x58
\x41\x77\x58
```

---

Os métodos que você usou consideram que a string representa um número na base 16 (por isso retorna `10`, pois 10 em hexadecimal é igual a `A`).